# Darksiders II on Steam

Tags: steam, darksiders-2

When I want to open Darksiders II's Steam store page I get to the starting page of the steam shop.

[image]

==>

[image]

It seems to be deleted from the store. When you search for the game there can only be found a `Darksiders II Deathinitive Edition` which can (currently) be purchased for 6,--€ (normal price: 29,99€, Germany). Furthermore this edition is evaluated very negatively (15% positive !!!).

When I google `Darksiders 2 Steam` the first pages also redirect me to the starting page of the steam store.

Is it a current bug (maybe because of the momentary sale?) or has Darksiders II - in the normal version which I have - been deleted from the Steam Store?

I can't find any statements for this. Do you know more about this issue?

Comment: I am not sure whether such kind of question are wanted to be seen here. Please point out to me when I move in a grey zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Deathinitive version of Darksiders II is an updated version of the original game from 2012. The original game is no longer available on Steam.

If you own the original version, you can buy the updated version for an 80% discount. If you owned the franchise pack (basically the game plus all DLC), you unlock the game for free. If you own neither, you still get a 20% discount.

The reason the updated version is scored so low is because most owners are experiencing crashes, lag and game breaking bugs. In addition, most users are not pleased that they have to spend money on it if they bought all the DLC separately in the past. This score might improve in the coming weeks and months, assuming the developers fix the bugs people are experiencing.

Comment: And when I uninstall my game now (I have neither season pass nor any DLC) will I able to download it again without purchasing the new edition? And how to play now the stable version when the new one crashes and is instable?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Yes.  It should remain in your library, which will allow you to re-download it.